# How can I export a JSON string with floats in the format 5.0f?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to make a Minecraft function compiler in Java, and data tags in Minecraft are very similar to JSON objects, but not quite the same. In general, they follow the JSON format, so I've been using JSONObjects, but for some reason, it wants me to have an 'f' after each float to show that they're floats, contrary to JSON standard of just writing the number.

Is it possible to export a JSON string with floats in that format without re-writing the whole exporter? If not, what's the best way to do this without writing spaghetti code? I will not need to re-parse it in Java.

Comment: Write it as a string?

Comment: {"valueOne":5.0f,"valueTwo":2.3f}. That's what I'm going for